# Does A* actually find the shortest path?

Tags: path-finding

It's said A* guarantees to find the shortest path but I think for certain paths with certain obstacles it won't find the nearest path. My example below is marked (with pink and blue lines) for what I think is the best path.

Maybe I don't know really the problem and its my mistake. Is that really a problem or weakness of A*? Are there any solutions for this?

[image]

im not sure that I think right about A* but I just in A* we just have an open list and closed list.  in A8 we just care about next step. so in every steo we see for every state with lowest F value and go the that state and put that state to closed list. am I right? its said that A* uses some back trackings. is that right?

Comment: Pathfinding solutions like A* are designed to find the "shortest" path.  Whether or not that's the "best" path is entirely subjective.  In your two examples, the paths are the same exact length because it seems to be set up to not allow diagonal movement.

Comment: @GuntherFox im telling even with permited diagonal movement, the result is the same

Comment: @virtouso: No, if you allow diagonal movement then you won't get the path going straight up. It's true that the heuristic cost will remain the same (for that initial going up part before going left around the wall), but the actual cost will be more expensive to go straight up so those nodes won't be on the final path. A* also takes into account the actual cost to get to each node, which is not shown in these images.

Comment: @milk can you tell me how those costs are designed? I know you can do many tricks to don't let agent go straight but basic of A* tell me with diagonal permited the movement will be the same if we just assume costs as straight distances. basic on A* just tells me f=g+h g is straight distance from goal and h is straight distance from start.

Comment: Your description of A* is not correct. The term h is the heuristic estimated cost from the node to the goal (often using a straight line heuristic), and g is the cost of the *least-cost path* from the start to the node, which in the general case might not be a straight line. This cost will vary depending on whether diagonal moves are permitted (at a cost of less than two orthogonal moves)

Comment: Within the constraints of your simulation, both paths are optimal. Count the number of nodes and you will see that they both take the same number of moves. When you have the goal to reach the target with the fewest number of moves then there is no objective reason to choose one over the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A* works with a [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)). Modifying the heuristic changes the outcome for your path. Depending on your needs, your heuristic will need to change to ensure what you define as an optimal path.

Your example shows three different algorithms.

The top left is Dijkstra’s Algorithm, which is mainly based on the number of steps taken from the source.

The top right example shows Greedy Best-First Search, which is mainly based on distance to the target (which can easily lead to non optimal paths).

Finally, the bottom center shows A*. A*'s heuristic is a combination of both of the above (steps taken from source and distance to target). This is the optimal path in for this scenario.

There are multiple equally optimal paths in this scenario. Your blue line shows one such example, and A* found another example. Since this heuristic is only concerned about minimizing the number of steps to reach the goal. Both examples have the same number of steps.

If this scenario allowed for diagonal movement, then your blue line path would indeed be a shorter path.

(For those that want to check out the included examples live, see [Amit's site](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html))

Comment: i think you can obviously find out that even if the diagonal move was permitted and those states just were some points in the map and costs just were reall distance the answer was just the same.  because you can simply know that A* only chooses min of summation of distance of current from destination and current from start. i think optimal answer is for the time that there is no obstacles. else it only gives and straight answer

Comment: Can you give an example of how A* is not finding an optimal path? What's not optimal about the path that A* finds in your example?

Comment: yes. sure. stay behind your pc

Comment: Assuming that you're only using [admissible heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), changing heuristics will only result in picking different paths of equivalent cost. If you need a fundamentally different search behavior (favoring diagonal movement, minimizing number of turns, etc), you must change the cost function as well.

Comment: @pikalek Yep, changing the heuristic could result in providing the diagonal-ish path the OP was requesting.

Comment: my friends. im just telling lets choose real distances as main heuristic cost for all possible moving states. the heuristic will be the same. I think my answer is in admissablity. the cost just I defined is not admissible because the path is that way. if I want to define another way with other cost function it like designing a way and I think its not logical way. but im going to use some unity standard A* code to see am I mistaken or not but im ilmost sure with basic impelementation of A* its not best way for such pathes. if say im wrong please tell the right cost function for such map